# Как передать массив из php в javascript

Tags: javascript

Получил массив из базы данных. Нужно обработать его в javascript. Помогите)

```
<?php
    $id1 = array("id" => "1", "name" => "block");
    $json = json_encode($id1);
?>
<script>
    var id1 = JSON.parse(<?php echo $json; ?>);
</script>
//Что я делаю не так в использовании JSON формата?
```

Comment: В самом `js` коде можна исмользовать метод пхп: `json_encode`. Пример: `var id1 = <?php echo json_encode($json) ?>;`

Comment: а какие ошибки в консоль джаваскрипт сыпятся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант попробуйте обернуть вывод в кавычки;

```
<script>
   var id1 = JSON.parse('<?php echo $json; ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: Приведите пример вывода <?php echo $json; ?>

Comment: @AlexChebotarsky Посмотрите в браузере исходный код полученной страницы.

Comment: Простите, за то давно задал вопрос и только сейчас отписываюсь. Зашёл в консоль (кстати не знал что консоль настолько удобный инструмент предупреждающий об ошибках в js, спасибо, теперь знаю), и увидел что в js вставился массив, естественно в формате json, но был без кавычек, добавил всё исправилось и побежал радостный дальше заканчивать модуль, и не поблагодарил своих спасителей, спасибо всем!

Answer (score 0):

а как вариант такой как раз чисто с масивами

```
  var id1 = <?php print_r($arr); ?>;
```

Comment: Для вашего примера не нужен собирать работающий код. Достаточно кнопки "Пример кода" (с фигурными кавычками) или просто отступ на 4 пробела.